# I am trying to show an image from an array of images - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I have one image showing on my homepage and want the user to click next image button so the next image in the array displays. I have seen similar questions and have tried resolving the issue, but nothing seems to work. I think the code is correct I just can't seem to get the images to display when the user hits 'Next Image'. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

JS:

```
var images = ["/aboutmepages/imagesAM/SSR.jpeg", "/aboutmepages/imagesAM/ATA.png",
  "/aboutmepages/imagesAM/BC.jpg", "/aboutmepages/imagesAM/GCU.jpg"
];

var current = 0; //current image displayed

var change_img = document.getElementById("placeholder");

function next() {
  if (current >= 0) {
    current = images.length;
    current++;
  }
  change_img.src = images[current].src;
}
```

HTML

```
  <img src="/aboutmepages/imagesAM/SSR.jpeg" id="placeholder">
    
    <div id="display">
        <button class="button" onclick="next()">Next Image</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: "If current_index is greater than or equal to zero, set the current_index to point to the last image, then increase it (so it now points to an invalid array item). Then, get the src of this invalid array item and set the change_img's src to be this invalid src.." - is that _really_ what you want your `next()` function to do??!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key issue is this line:

```
change_img.src = images[current].src;
```

It should be

```
change_img.src = images[current];
```

as you don't have `src` properties on any of the elements in the array, just strings at array indexes.

Instead of checking that `current >= 0` (we already know that it's going to be zero), check that `current` is less than the array length (because arrays use a zero-based index).

```js
const images = [
  'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/00ff00/000',
  'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/0000ff/fff',
  'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff',
  'https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff/000',
];

const placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', next, false);

let current = 0;

function next() {
  if (current < images.length) {
    placeholder.src = images[current];
    ++current;
  }
}

next();
```

```html
<button>Next</button>
<img id="placeholder" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `src` as the `image` in the `images` array with using the `current` index

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
function next() {
  if (current === images.length) current = 0;
  change_img.src = images[current++];
}
```

**`NOTE: I've used lorem-picsum for demo purpose. You can add yours link`**

```js
var images = [
  "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/200",
  "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/200",
  "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
  "https://picsum.photos/200"
];

var current = 0; //current image displayed

var change_img = document.getElementById("placeholder");

function next() {
  if (current === images.length) current = 0;
  change_img.src = images[current++];
}

const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", next);
```

```html
<div id="display">
  <button class="button">Next Image</button>
</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200" id="placeholder" />
```

Comment: Your "next image" button doesn't move to the next image.

Comment: @Andy It is working in my local, Don't know why it is not working in SOF. But now it is working